# Server cannot mount /usr filesystem. the disk drive for /usr is not ready yet or not present

Tags: 14.04, reboot

After a cold reboot server fails to mount file system `/usr`
When I skip mount, it boots but `:/usr/bin/env: not found`. Basically, I cannot run any commands.

Comment: cn you give us some more information? partition table, fstab contents, boot race?

Comment: Hi, I cannot run any commands, I am stuck

Comment: boot from a LiveCD

Comment: Is it possible without loosing data have a MySQL database that I need

Comment: Boot recovery mode, enter root option, type `cat /etc/fstab`. You will not loose anything typing just this command, because at this point, root partition is read-only mounted.

Comment: @Redbob looks kinda like this   
# / was on /dev/sda2 during instllation 
UUID=9443e335-9d6e-4f6b-ae38-c3bb9ed17f8f     /                       ext4 errors=remount-ro   0   1 
# /home / was on /dev/sda3 during instllation     /home
UUID..........................................................................................                         ext4   defaults   0 2

# /usr was on /dev/sdb1 during instllation
UUID=9443e335-9d6e-4f6b-ae38-c3bb9ed17f8f     /usr                     ext4 defaults   0    2

Comment: Geoffrey, these info are a bit fuzzy. Post into your question (not at comments) the output of these commands: `lsblk` and `blkid`.